# Translating the `on` pattern to Backbone's `event` hash

Tags: backbone.js

Inside my Backbone views, in the `initialize` function I do stuff like:

```
initialize: function () {
    $(this.el).on('click', '.button', function () {
        $(this).fadeTo(0.5);
    }
}
```

This seems to go against Backbone's convention of using `events`. Rewriting with the `events` hash:

```
events: { 'click .button': 'fadeButton' },
fadeButton: function () {
    $(this).fadeTo(0.5);
}
```

The problem is inside `fadeButton`'s scope the value of `this` is not the same as when using `.on()`. What is the correct way of doing this using the `events` hash?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like paul said, Backbone automatically sets the context for event callbacks to the view itself. So `this` in the callback will be the view instance.

So you can get the effect you intend by using the view's scoped selector function...

```
events: { 
  'click .button': 'fadeButton' 
},

fadeButton: function () {
  this.$('.button').fadeTo(0.5);
}
```

... but if you've got multiple elements with class `"button"` in your view, that'll fade *all* of them, in which case you can always use the event object that jQuery gives you to get the event target:

```
fadeButton: function (event) {
  $(event.target).fadeTo(0.5);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about `event.target` but it goes against the jQuery philosophy, and is yucky

Answer (score 0):

You defined the events hash correctly.

And for every event handler defined, Backbone automatically sets the context to the view. So `this` within `fadeButton` is the view, and you will want to access the view's element.

The code below shows how you need to update the `fadeButton` function.

```
fadeButton: function () {
  $(this.el).fadeTo(0.5);
}
```

Comment: It is not `this.el` that should be faded, but the elements inside `this.el` that have class `.button`.